# Wigner 's unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in natural sciences

Tags: differential-equations, phase-space, chaos-theory, models, complex-systems

This question is related to [Wigner's problem](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html),  related to the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics in natural sciences.  Understanding a phenomenon means constructing a mathematical model , and understanding the topological structure of the phase space associated to the  behavior of the system under consideration, under certain circumstances,  and predicting its future behavior.

Could the answer to Wigner's problem reside in the concept of attractor reconstruction, in particular [Takens' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens%27s_theorem),  which states that you can obtain a structure that is topologically equivalent to an attractor by means of a delay embedding,  or a  differential embedding,  since time derivatives can be approximated by delay coordinates? When faced with a nonlinear complex system (generating strange attractors in phase space ),  Takens' theorem guarantees the existence of a sufficiently simplistic model that justifies the experimental data,  at least under a limited variance of the parameters involved. Could this perspective answer Wigner's question,  and open a systematic way to extend current physics theories?

Comment: Physics SE is **not** a discussion-type forum so questions that involve asking for opinions (off-topic in it's own right), comments and debate will generally be off-topic.

Comment: @StephenG  You know what they say,  "don't look a gift horse in the mouth ".  I am not sufficiently trained to take this idea further,  but hopefully someone else will. I agree this is not mainstream,  but it's not nonsense either,  and it could answer a profound question in physics.  Be that as it may, this is a legitimate mathematical question.